# Jfrog Artifactory with Rancher and Helm Integration

Tags: kubernetes-helm, artifactory, rancher, jfrog-container-registry

I have:

**JFROG Artifactory Docker repository** - Pro On-Prem version.

Rancher server - v2.6.8

**Kubernetes cluster** installed on-prem with **RKE1** provider - on premise.

**I have 2 questions:**

1. how do I work with (or add) my own JFROG Artifactory Docker repository from the Rancher Gui server?

In GUI I saw there are 2 options:
HTTP URL
Git repository

2. how do I deploy microservices applications using Helm with my  JFROG Artifactory Docker repository from Rancher?

Comment: 1) The JFROG Artifactory is available through the Rancher catalog. Did you check these guides https://www.rancher.cn/setting-docker-registry-jfrog-artifactory-rancher, https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Integration+with+Rancher+Catalog+Helm+Chart ?

2) You have to specify in the Helm where to get the Docker images, that includes the path of the JFrog Artifactory

Comment: I already have jfrog artifactory repository.. I just want to connect it to Rancher.

Comment: If you want to use the JFrog Artifactory on Rancher you have to add it from the catalog. Otherwise, if you want to use it on-premise you specify through Helm where the repo is by adding the repo to Helm (helm repo add <name> <url>, helm repo update).
Maybe this link can help https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Kubernetes+Helm+Chart+Repositories

Comment: Can I do it from Gui server(adding my opn repository)? if yes, how?

Comment: You should be able to do it on Rancher UI from "App & Marketplace" -> "Repositories". There you can add custom repositories

Comment: I have tried but I am getting some error of: "Failed to parse response from https://artifactory.name.com:6646/index.yaml".do I need to install first helm on Rancher?